# I try to add wordpress blog to existing PHP Laravel project

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have a PHP Laravel project hosted on Heroku with a Postgresql database and I want to add a Wordpress blog to /blog.

I added in the public folder a blog folder and then copied the last version of WordPress there.

After that, I followed, starting with step 6, this tutorial: `http://www.merocode.com/hosting-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-with-support-of-postgres/`. I also replaced the wp_config variables with the ones provided on Heroku.

After deploying it to Heroku and trying to test my_site.herokuapp.com/blog I get:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /app/public/blog/wp-content/pg4wp/core.php(32) : eval()'d code on line 1612
>
> Connecting to your PostgreSQL database without a password is considered insecure.
> If you want to do it anyway, please set "PG4WP_INSECURE" to true in your "db.php" file.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Do you know another good tutorial with all the steps that can help me host a WordPress blog to an existing PHP Laravel project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel and Wordpress should be separated!
This error is not related to Laravel. Check your Wordpress files and versions or your webserver config.

**Correct solution:**

Create a new config in your webserver and define new routes for /blog and separate your project folders.

Comment: I added a new blog folder in the public folder and locally it is working fine. The problem is when I try to run this using Heroku and Postgres.